# The beauty of referencing Torah-sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, commentaries, rashi, kanievsky

Rashi, [in several places](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99&tab=text&tpathFilters=Talmud%20Commentary%2FRishonim%20on%20Talmud%2FRashi&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance), says "לא ידעתי" - I don't know. It is said that Rabbi Akiva Eiger made a list of the times Rashi said "לא ידעתי" - I don't know, people were bothered by that, and asked Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l why Rabbi Akiva Eiger wrote something like this.

Rav Chaim Kanievsky zt"l is quoted in saying that there is a certain beauty in pointing out where certain ideas can be found in Torah-sources.

> שמעתי ממו"ח שא' שאל את רבינו ע"ד הגרע"א בגליון הש"ס ברכות כ"ח ע"ב שעל מש"כ רש"י שם לא ידעתי מציין הגרע"א עוד הרבה מקומות בש"ס שכת' רש"י שאינו יודע ומה הענין בזה וכי בא להראות עד כמה רש"י לא יודע והשיבו רבינו שיש יופי וחביבות מיוחד לתורה כשמציינים היכן יש עוד ענין כזה בש"ם וכעין ממורת הש"ם שכל פעם כשאדם לומד דבר מזכיר לעצמו היכן עוד למד כן ולכן גם הגרע"א כשראה דברי רש"י אלו ציין לעצמו מיד היכן עוד ראה כן ברש"י וכתב רק מה שזכר ברגע זו אבל לא חיפש היכן עוד רש"י לא יודע
>
> [(sefer: Minchas Todah, p. 5, sv. ציצין ופרחים לתורה)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/168332/p/5/t/0.76083779577161211234/fs/MingC28gvVSj1ADBoD4v3Be3xLzlLP38T37e8L8gMOGg/start/0/end/18/c)

Why is this considered beautifying the Torah? Why is it, that if you found a certain idea, and you explain that this idea can also be found in maseches x, or in posuk x, that this is considered as if you are making "flowers of Torah"?

Comment: We do find in some places eg. Tosfos that the discussion is extended and expanded for the sake of להגדיל תורה ולהדירה

Comment: Personally I find it very beautiful so I try to do it whenever I can

Comment: @Moishe Okay, but why is referencing considered beautifying Torah?